# Simple tax calculation in Scala

Tags: scala, numeric, tax

Suppose I am writing a toy tax calculator with two functions:

```
// calculate the tax amount for a particular income given tax brackets
def tax(income: BigDecimal, brackets: Seq[Bracket]): BigDecimal = ???

// calculate the min. income for a particular tax rate given tax brackets 
def income(taxRate: BigDecimal, brackets: Seq[Bracket]) = ???
```

I define a tax bracket like this:

```
case class Bracket(maxIncomeOpt: Option[BigDecimal], rate: BigDecimal)
```

`Bracket(Some(BigDecimal(10)), BigDecimal(10))` means a tax bracket of `10%` for income up tp `10` 
`Bracket(Some(BigDecimal(20)), BigDecimal(20))` means a tax bracket of `20%` for income up tp `20`
`Bracket(None, BigDecimal(30))` means a tax bracket of `30%` for any income

Now I am writing function `tax` like this:

```
def tax(income: BigDecimal, brackets: Seq[Bracket]): BigDecimal = {
  val (_, result) = brackets.foldLeft((BigDecimal(0), income)) { case ((result, rest), curr) =>
    val taxable = curr.maxIncomeOpt.fold(rest)(_.min(rest))
    (result + taxable * curr.rate / 100.0, rest - taxable)
  }
  result
}
```

Function `tax` seems working but think `Seq[Bracket]` is not the best way to define tax brackets. The tax brackets is a sorted sequence of disjoint "back-to-back" intervals with an open interval at the end. How would you define tax brackets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider solution using algebraic data types to define brackets and `PositiveInfinity` to simulate open interval

```
abstract class TaxBracket(val from: Double, val to: Double, val rate: Double) {
  def tax(income: Double) = {
    if (income >= from)
      if (to.isPosInfinity) (income - from) * rate
      else if (income - to > 0) (to - from) * rate
      else (income - (from - 1)) * rate
    else
      0.0
  }
}
case object A extends TaxBracket(0, 12500, 0.0)
case object B extends TaxBracket(12501, 50000, 0.2)
case object C extends TaxBracket(50001, 150000, 0.4)
case object D extends TaxBracket(150001, Double.PositiveInfinity, 0.45)
```

Now tax calculation simplifies to

```
def tax(income: Double, bands: List[TaxBracket]): Double =
  bands.map(_.tax(income)).sum
```

for example, using [UK tax bands](https://www.gov.uk/income-tax-rates) defined above we get

```
tax(60000, List(A, B, C, D)) // res0: Double = 11499.8
```

which can be verified [here](https://www.uktaxcalculators.co.uk/).

To get the minimum income for given effective tax rate, try

```
def income(etr: Double, bands: List[TaxBracket]): Option[Double] = {
  bands.map(b => (b.from, b.to)).find { case (from, to) =>
    if (to.isPosInfinity) true
    else (tax(to, bands) / to) >= etr
  }.map { case (lowerBound, upperBound) => lowerBound }
}

income(0.4, List(A, B, C, D)) // res1: Option[Double] = Some(150001.0)
```

Comment: Nice ! Thank you. This solution looks really simpler. How would you implement `income` function to calculate the min. income with a given effective tax rate ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest much the same, a `List[Tuple[Double, Double]]` as the raw form.

Where the tuple is semantically `(lower_bound, tax_rate_in_range)`. The key difference is that the atomic unit of behaviour is the tax schedule, not the individual brackets. Within a schedule defined by this core data, you can add optimisations if the number brackets becomes large, and you can preserve important invariant for the naive solution like keeping the list ordered by the `lower_bound`.

Answer (score 1):

I would define tax brackets as a piecewise constant function :

```
def taxBracket(i: Int): Float = {
  case _ if i < 10 => 0.1
  case _ if i < 20 => 0.2
  case _ => 0.3
}
```

It's easy to read, easy to have custom behaviours for any kind of value (let's say it becomes linear somewhere or anything in fact, you can just tie the pieces as you want), and calculating the tax for amount N is simply the numerical integration of this function between 0 and N.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you are right and such a function is a better way to model tax brackets. How would you write `tax` and `income` functions in this case ?